# Pasting Rows B2:B16 from Sheet 2 onto Newly Inserted column on Sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to have a macro insert a column on sheet "Runs", and then paste information from sheet "Templates" onto the newly inserted column on a specific Row.  I have named the range for row four as "Eight", however, info from templates is pasted onto column A, Row 4, and not the newly inserted column.

```
Set myWorksheet = Worksheets("Runs")
myFirstColumnT = myWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
                                         What:="TS", _
                                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                                    

    myLastColumnT = myWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
                                         What:="TE", _
                                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                                         
    For iCounter = myLastColumnT To (myFirstColumnT + 1) Step -100000000
        myWorksheet.Columns(iCounter).Insert
        Sheets("Templates").Select
        Range("B2:B16").Copy
        Sheets("Runs").Select
        With Columns(iCounter).Select
            Range("eight").PasteSpecial
        End With
    Next iCounter
```

Comment: If `Range("eight")` references the _whole_ row, then you have to specify the column as well, like `Sheets("Runs").range("eight").cells(1,iCounter)`.pastespecial.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `With` doesn't actually do anything and if it did your `Range` doesn't reference it.

I've removed your loop, it has such a massive step it isn't actually looping anything. Also you don't need a loop for this.

I removed the `.column` from your `.finds` because that will cause an error if it fails, I also added in some error checking for if (when) it doesn't find anything.

I removed all instances of `.Select` because they aren't necessary.

```
    Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myfirstcolumnt As Range
    Dim mylastcolumnt As Range
    
    Dim newcol As Long
    Set myworksheet = Worksheets("Runs")

    'I'm assuming you need this for a reason other than the loop, otherwise you can remove it
    Set myfirstcolumnt = myworksheet.Cells.Find( _
                                         What:="TS", _
                                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                                    
    If myfirstcolumnt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "TS not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set mylastcolumnt = myworksheet.Cells.Find( _
                                         What:="TE", _
                                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If mylastcolumnt Is Nothing Then 'Avoiding errors
        MsgBox "TE not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    newcol = mylastcolumnt.Column + 1 'No need to loop to find the column you're making
    myworksheet.Columns(newcol).Insert 'use the new column index to add the column
    Sheets("Templates").Range("b2:b16").Copy 
    myworksheet.Cells(4, newcol).PasteSpecial 'We know it's going in row 4 and we have the new column index now
```

If you want to use your named range you can do `myworksheet.Cells(myworksheet.range("Eight").Row, newcol)...` Though I suggest changing the name, a range called "Eight" pointing to Row 4 isn't very clear.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, so there is more to this code that I didn't feel the need to allude to.  I am developing a scheduling tool.  B2:B16 is the time it takes to complete one day of operations.  So, in theory, if someone wanted to see what it looked like to have 5 starts of an operation on Tuesday, I would have to add the specified number of columns on tuesday and paste the B2:B16 Range there.  Why I am denoting row 4 as eight is because that is the time of day we start our process and rows 4 through 25 are 30 minute time increments from 0800-1830  Again, thank you so much!